# Are there existing performance measurement libraries on android that support ping, throughput and so on?

Tags: android, performance, ping, measurement, throughput

I am developing an Android app that needs to know the network performance such as latency, bandwidth and so on. I am wondering whether there is already such an library so that I can directly cooperate it into my code and I don't need to implement it on my own.

Any recommendations will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are so many apps that do this already. You have to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at Mobilyzer, it is an open source mobile measurement library for Android apps. It supports a rich set of  measurements including ping, tcp throughput, udp burst, dns look up and so on. Mobilyzer has a very easy to use API. For example, you can issue a ping measurement and retrieve the results within ~10 lines of code.

You can have a look at their webpage [here](http://mobilyzer-project.mobi) to get more information. The source code of Mobilyzer can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mobilyzer/Mobilyzer)

Comment: Thanks. This library seems to fit my needs.